# Display custom value for objects in Flash Builder Debugger variables view

Tags: flash, debugging, flash-builder

Is there a way display a custom text for the values of objects in the variables view of the flash builder debugger?

String and numbers get to display its value, but other objects display the class name and [possibly] a memory location. That value column is the one that I wonder can display something  different.

[image: Variables view of Flash Builder]

Comment: It would be neat if it called toString() on the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that currently there is no way to modify what is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a toString() method then open up the Expressions view and type in the variable name, calling toString(). In your case, it would be questMDO.toString(). This should output whatever value you want, as defined in the method. Pretty sure it is not possible to do in the Variables view though.

Comment: Yep, I am aware of that other option, but i am still looking for it to work right in the variables view, which would be very convenient.